# Не работает конкатенация в курсоре TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

Пытаюсь соединить строки в курсоре, а в результате - пустота (MS SQL 2008):

```
        DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR
        WITH FullAddress(SHORTNAME,OFFNAME,AOLEVEL,PARENTGUID) AS
        (
            SELECT SHORTNAME,OFFNAME,AOLEVEL,PARENTGUID
            FROM dbo.ADDROBJ
            WHERE AOID = @aoid
            UNION ALL
            SELECT A.SHORTNAME,A.OFFNAME,A.AOLEVEL,A.PARENTGUID
            FROM dbo.ADDROBJ A INNER JOIN FullAddress AS F
            ON A.AOGUID = F.PARENTGUID
        )
        SELECT SHORTNAME,OFFNAME FROM FullAddress
        ORDER BY AOLEVEL


        OPEN curs
        FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @shortname,@offname
        SET @addrStr+= (@shortname+'. '+@offname);
        FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @shortname,@offname
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @addrStr+= (', '+@shortname+'. '+@offname); 
            FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @shortname,@offname                   
        END
        CLOSE curs
        DEALLOCATE curs
        PRINT @addrStr
```

Вывод переменной `@addrStr` дает пустое значение.
Что не так?

Действительно, я был неправ инициализируя строку значением NULL.
Заработало. Спасибо Mike.

Comment: А где вы `@addrStr` объявляете и как инициализируете. просто если она NULL, то после += она так же NULL и останется. Если ее сделать изначально `set @addrStr='';` то должно работать ...

Comment: А использовать курсор — это вообще принципиальное требование? Не проще ли было обойтись, например, `SELECT`'ом  `... FOR XML PATH`?

Comment: У меня там курсор на рекурсивный запрос, который обходит дерево и строит строку адреса исходя из ID объекта переданного в процедуру. БД это урезанный ФИАС. Результат должен выглядеть как форматированная строка адреса.

Comment: Приведите полный скрипт с курсором, возможно курсора можно избежать. Что вероятнее всего повысит производительность(если, конечно, она в данной задаче нужна).

Comment: Остальное обвес в виде объявлений переменных... По поводу производительности. Запрос будет вызываться для формы асинхронно по требованию пользователя и при формировании отчета. Думаю тут частого обращения не будет.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @addrStr varchar(8000);
SET @addrStr = '';

OPEN curs
FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @shortname,@offname
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --PRINT @shortname;
    SET @addrStr = @addrStr + '(' + ISNULL(@shortname,'') + '. ' + ISNULL(@offname,'') + ')';
    FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @shortname,@offname           
END
CLOSE curs;
DEALLOCATE curs;

SELECT @addrStr;
```

Comment: += на 2008  сервере уже работает, можно было оставить. но всё равно +1:)

Answer (score 2):

Избегайте курсоров, если можно обойтись без них. В данном случае можно:

```
declare @addrStr nvarchar(max);

WITH FullAddress(SHORTNAME,OFFNAME,AOLEVEL,PARENTGUID) AS
(
    ...
)
SELECT @addrStr = STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + SHORTNAME + '. ' + OFFNAME
    FROM FullAddress
    ORDER BY AOLEVEL
    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).VALUE('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '');
```